# what is the approx memory overhead for a SSL connection in node.js

Tags: node.js, memory, ssl, openssl

I am using node version v0.8.16. 
It bundles with openssl 1.0.0f and contains `SSL_OP_NO_COMPRESSION` and `SSL_MODE_RELEASE_BUFFERS`.

My test ssl server just echoes back hello world upon incoming https request and keep the connection open.
From my test, the memory overhead per ssl connection is around 150k.

What is the approximate memory overhead for ssl connections in node ? 
how can I reduce ssl memory usage in this case ?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

SSL needs per-connection space for:

- the socket FD
- about 16k for a receive buffer for the maximum possible SSL record, which varies slightly with the cipher suite
- an output buffer, probably also about 16k
- space to compute per-message MACs in
- handshake status, connection status, handshake MAC, etc.
- a pointer to the SSL session, which is shareable among connections to the same target, and which must contain the cipher suite, protocol, premaster secret, shared secret, session ID, peer certificate chain, timeout variables, ...
- whatever else I haven't thought of.

In addition the TCP connection will consume kernel space, e.g. for the socket send and receive buffers.

Comment: Great list! Also I have to add that as most implementations are not tightly linked with "consumer" (the application code), and consumers don't know or care about SSL/tLS internals, there also exist buffers for decoded data (after receiving) and for data before sending. Such buffers take even more space, than the rest of stuff. Such buffers can be optimized in specific cases, but not always.

Comment: @EugeneMayevski'EldoSCorp You usually need a plaintext receive buffer, but you don't really need a plaintext send buffer: and with suitable API design you don't need any of them. The JSSE SSLEngine for example relies on the application to provide all four.

Comment: Right, it "relies on the application" which means that buffers are still present ;)

Comment: @EugeneMayevski'EldoSCorp I would say you can't really count the application (plaintext) send buffer as part of the cost of an SSL connection. It would be there in the application in any case. If the application is providing the app. receive buffer the same applies.

Comment: This is not exactly so. In plain FTP, for example, your data buffer (with proper implementation, of course) could travel down to IP driver without copying (just memory pages are remapped). As soon as SSL is added, the need for additional buffers arise. BTW we also missed compression buffers used for compression.

Comment: Also, I am not saying that it's not possible to get rid of those extra buffers - it's possible and it's done in restricted environments, but one would trade flexibility for memory optimization (or vice versa).

Comment: @EugeneMayevski'EldoSCorp That's my point. There has to be an plaintext send buffer, in the application space, so you can't count it as a per-connection cost peculiar to SSL.

Answer (score 3):

SSL needs about 128K or even more (depending on implementation) per connection for memory buffers so you probably won't be able to reduce amount of memory used.

Comment: I am using node with openssl 1.0.0f. can you point me to some document for this ? Is it possible to reduce the size of memory buffer ?

Comment: @haijin document for what are you asking about? This is the way SSL works. We as implementors of the SSL/TLS engine know this, but I doubt that you will find any document stating "128 Kb is required for SSL". And as I have written there's no way to reduce the buffer size cause in this case SSL engine won't be able to work.

Comment: Yes, I know openssl doc sucks and I am new to ssl so I am wondering whether there is a set of constant or structure define the size of memory buffers for SSL connection. I found in openssl crypto/bio/bf_buff.c, the default size for bio ibuf/obuf are 4096 and the doc says you can not reduce below 4k. This is just one bio buffer ctx. I think that's just one portion of the memory buffer you mentioned. I am trying to find some documentation regarding the memory usage, and the detailed break down of the memory for SSL connection on the server side.